# Is it possible to make an afterimage (multiple exposure) like effect in EEVEE 2.9?

Tags: animation, eevee-render-engine, effects

I'm trying to make an afterimage like effect, don't know if that's actually what its called, but can't figure it out nor can I find anyone talking about it, at least for EEVEE. I've tried particle system and an add-on called magic trails, but it's not working. It needs to work with armature.

Blender 2.92 and EEVEE

[image: Anime example of waving arms]
[image: "8 bit" example of running character]
[image: another example of a running character]

Comment: Looks for me like you could make it with just copies of your object with the same animation (with some time difference) and different color/saturation/alpha values

Comment: I'll save that as a last resort. I'm trying to find a more effective, procedural and time effective way.